# How to perform a for each statement in java with an ArrayList?

Tags: java, foreach

Is there a foreach statement in java that I can use to create a string from an ArrayList such as:

```
ArrayList<String> captured_photos=new ArrayList<String>();
captured_photos.add("pic1");
captured_photos.add("pic2");
String MyMessage="";
foreach(AnElement,My_ArrayList){MyMessage+=AnElement+", ";}
```

That will create MyMessage: "pic1, pic2, "?

Comment: Just google java for each and you'll get your answer.

Comment: It's called enhanced for loop.

Comment: Java 8 provides another way to join `ArrayList` elements together as strings with a separator: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

Comment: http://javaloop.co.uk/#for

See enhanced for loop, it has an example almost exactly of what you want.